# Running Go server behind Nginx Reverse Proxy with SSL

Tags: ssl, go, nginx

I've done some digging through the interwebs and haven't been able to come across anything similar (at least near any solution that has worked out for me).

Essentially, I am running a Golang server locally on `127.0.0.1:1337`, I want this to be accessible globally so I use Nginx to forward traffic from `https://api.example.com/` to my API to retrieve information.

With that being said, I have simply setup my Golang server to listen and serve on port **`1337`** and my Nginx configuration is setup to redirect all HTTP traffic (for all domains) to HTTPS:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _; 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and then I redirect traffic to port 1337 here:

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;   
}
```

The issue with this is that I find myself to keep getting redirects from HTTPS to HTTP (as per *wget*) and I end up getting a `Too Many Redirects` error.

If anyone can provide some guidance, I'd very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server_name _;` matches server name that can not find matches.

I have done that before.

See my nginx config to proxy api backend:

```
# ssl
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert/live/ybilly.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert/live/ybilly.com/privkey.pem;

# http to https
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name ybilly.com www.ybilly.com *.ybilly.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# api backend
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name *.ybilly.com;

  location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_read_timeout                 900;
    proxy_buffers 32 4k;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }

}
```

Comment: This did not fix it, I am still experiencing an infinite redirects issue.

Comment: It works for me. So how about check the difference between yours and mine? Or maybe there are other configs you did not show in the `nginx.conf.d` affect this issue.

Comment: It appeared to be an issue with Cloudflare, I've fixed those issues and everything seems to be resolved.

Comment: Not to mention, your answer did also help so I'll mark it as the answer since there were two problems, you fixed the big one.

Comment: Ah, It’s ok. I got great pleasures when I saw my reputation growing up these days. Haaaa. That's my motivation to give help.